# Why do I encounter this error: "time.replaceAll is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hello I keep getting a error of "time.replaceAll is not a function" and I cant figure out why since I tried `time.replaceAll` in a online code editor and it worked.

```
exports.ForgotPasswordToken = async (req, res) => {
  username = req.body.username;
  const add_minutes = function (dt, minutes) {
    return new Date(dt.getTime() + minutes * 60000);
  };
  const time = add_minutes(new Date(), 10).toString();
  const decimalTime = time.replaceAll(":", "").substr("16", "6");
  const tokenExp = decimalTime;
  const token = Math.random()
    .toString(24)
    .replace(/[^a-z]+/g, "")
    .substr(0, 5);
  hashed_token = bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    bcrypt.hash(token, salt, (err, hash) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  });

  await User.findOne({ username: username }, (err, obj) => {
    const userEmail = obj.email;
  });

  let newToken = new Token({
    tokenUser: username,
    tokenVal: hashed_token,
    tokenExpiration: tokenExp,
  });

  const resetLink = `https://localhost:5000/password/reset/${token}/${username}`;
  newToken.save();
  passwordResetEmail(username, userEmail, resetLink);
  res.redirect("/login");
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`String.prototype.replaceAll` is a very new feature that [only recently](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll#Browser_compatibility) became available in JS environments. If you want to use it in Node, either upgrade to Node 15 (15.0.0 is the earliest Node version that supports it), or use a regular expression instead:

```
time.replace(/:/g, '')
```

Comment: Thanks i understand